# assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context --- how to resolve this error

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to find the find the result of num1 raised to the power num2:
This is my code ->

```
 fun power(num1 : Int, num2: Int): Int {
      var result = 1
      while (num2 != 0) {
       return  result *= num1
       num2--
      }
    }
```

But the above code is producing the following error -->

```
Calculator.kt:30:16: error: assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context
       return  result *= num1
               ^
Calculator.kt:33:5: error: a 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')
    } 
    ^
```

I have read a number of articles but not able to understand. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression is something that evaluates to a value. An assignment is something that assigns a value to a variable or property.

`x *= y` is an assignment that is shorthand for `x = x * y`.

You cannot return an assignment, because it does not evaluate to a value. An assignment contains an expression on the right side of the equals sign, but as a whole does not represent an expression.

There are some other syntax problems you have. You can't modify a function paramter's value (`num2--` isn't allowed).

The logic also doesn't make sense. `return` returns an expression immediately. To fix your code, you need to create a local variable from `num2`, and move the return statement to the end.

```
fun power(num1 : Int, num2: Int): Int {
    var result = 1
    var count = num2
    while (count != 0) {
        result *= num1
        count--
    }
    return result
}
```

FYI, there's a function called `repeat` that is simpler than using a while loop with a counter. It runs the code inside the brackets by the number of times you give.

```
fun power(num1 : Int, num2: Int): Int {
    var result = 1
    repeat(num2) {
        result *= num1
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You function contains multiple errors, I suggest you to study Kotlin, [here](https://superkotlin.com/kotlin-mega-tutorial/) a reference. Kotlin website has some more material.

Back to your problem, I have modified your function:

```
fun power(num1 : Int, num2: Int): Int {
  var result = 1
  var num2_local = num2
  while (num2_local != 0) {
   result *= num1
   num2_local--
  }
  return result
}
```

Problems with your version:

- you return from the function immediately
- basic types args passed to kotlin functions are passed by const copy, this means that you cannot modify them (e.g *num2--*)

If you keep a local modifiable reference (var keyword) withing your function, then you achieve your goal